# error on creating a invoice pdf in php

Tags: php, sql, fpdf

Please help on solving my myth on creating a simple invoice detail php code as below....  I have 2 tables as "a_sales" and "a_sales_detail"  and I try to create an invoice pdf.  Now it won't show at all.....

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">Item Information</div>
 <div class="panel-body">
 <?php
 $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ";
 "`a_sales_detail`.`Sales_Quantity` AS `OrderQTY`,";
 "`a_sales_detail`.`Stock_Item` AS `Item`,";
 "`a_sales_detail`.`Item_Description` AS `Description`,";
 "`a_sales_detail`.`Sales_Price` AS `UnitPrice`";
 "`a_sales_detail`.`Sales_Total_Amount ` AS `Subtotal`";

 " FROM ` a_sales ` JOIN `a_sales_detail ` ON (`a_sales`.`Sales_Number` = `a_sales_detail`.`Sales_Number`)";

 echo $dbhelper->ExecuteHtml($sql, array("fieldcaption" => TRUE, "tablename" => array("a_sales", "a_sales_detail"))); 
?>
```

Comment: Examine the output of `echo $sql` (Not sure if the spaces are significant here; `\` a_sales \``)

Comment: Thank you Alex, but I tried to remove the space in between and still not working.....

Answer (score 0):

$sql is simply assigned "SELECT DISTINCT " and nothing else. You might want to replace the semicolon after that line with a dot as you want the following line to be also part of that SQL-statement. There might be more of those replacements necessary.

You should check when to use a dot instead of a semicolon in PHP.